# Cleaned up camera osx and opencv

Tags: c, macos, opencv

hi guys i am executing some sample programs at my macbook using opencv and this is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    IplImage  *frame = 0;
    int       key = 0;

    /* initialize camera */
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

   /* always check */
    if ( !capture ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    /* create a window for the video */
    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    while(1>0)
    {
        /* get a frame */
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        /* always check */
        if(!frame ) break;

        /* display current frame */
        cvShowImage( "result", frame );

         waitKey(10);

        /* exit if user press 'Esc' */
        key = cvWaitKey( 20 );

        if((char)key==27 )
            break;

    }

    /* free memory */
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "result" );
    return 0;
}
```

the code was working fine on the Macbookpro about a year ago ( OSX snow leopard ) but at the macbook (lion) i only get this at the console: Cleaned up camera. No isight, no image... nothing, only that message? any advise o.0?

ps? i changed the number at Caoture FromCAM to 300 ( iEEE cameras ) or 500 (quicktime ) then i have no message but still no image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, apparently is an issue on the current opencv version 2.6.x. I unistalled ffmpeg `brew uninstall ffmepg` and opencv `brew uninstall opencv`

then i changed my opencv version `cd /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science` i searched other version ( isight was working under 4.5.5 ) `brew versions opencv` and i added the 2.4.5 `git chekout ae74fe9 opencv.rb` finally i installed opencv using `brew install opencv` and it is done isight works great :).

ps: isight camera will work with cvCaptureFromCAM( 500 ) not 0, -1 or 300.
ps2: omg i am so happy :3